# R unable to install or load my package with devtools, infinite "Loading..." loop

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

After a fresh installation of R 4.1.2 and `devtools`, I tried to install a personnal package (named biostat2 below, an old collection of functions I use).

But the installation, and even the simple loading (with `load_all() function) failed. I observe in the console that R tries to load the package several times without succeeding, ending with an error.

I wish I could say more, but I really have no idea what's going on. Would you have any idea to point me to the origin of this problem?

```
> load_all()
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
ℹ Loading biostat2
Erreur : C stack usage  7978548 is too close to the limit
Erreur dans del_from:length(app$styles) : Argument NA / NaN
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
Erreur dans unload(package) : 
  Package biostat2 not found in loaded packages or namespaces
```

My sessionInfo:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.10.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.10.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=fr_FR.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=fr_FR.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=fr_FR.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_FR.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] devtools_2.4.3  usethis_2.1.5   flextable_0.7.0 officer_0.4.2  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.8.3      lattice_0.20-45   prettyunits_1.1.1 ps_1.7.0          rprojroot_2.0.3   digest_0.6.29     utf8_1.2.2       
 [8] R6_2.5.1          evaluate_0.15     pillar_1.7.0      gdtools_0.2.4     rlang_1.0.2       uuid_1.1-0        rstudioapi_0.13  
[15] data.table_1.14.2 callr_3.7.0       Matrix_1.4-0      rmarkdown_2.14    desc_1.4.1        splines_4.1.2     stringr_1.4.0    
[22] compiler_4.1.2    xfun_0.30         pkgconfig_2.0.3   systemfonts_1.0.4 base64enc_0.1-3   pkgbuild_1.3.1    htmltools_0.5.2  
[29] tibble_3.1.6      roxygen2_7.1.2    fansi_1.0.3       crayon_1.5.1      withr_2.5.0       brio_1.1.3        grid_4.1.2       
[36] lifecycle_1.0.1   magrittr_2.0.3    zip_2.2.0         cli_3.3.0         stringi_1.7.6     cachem_1.0.6      fs_1.5.2         
[43] remotes_2.4.2     testthat_3.1.3    xml2_1.3.3        ellipsis_0.3.2    vctrs_0.4.1       nortest_1.0-4     tools_4.1.2      
[50] glue_1.6.2        purrr_0.3.4       processx_3.5.3    pkgload_1.2.4     fastmap_1.1.0     survival_3.2-13   sessioninfo_1.2.2
[57] memoise_2.0.1     knitr_1.38
```

Comment: It would help to show your package code. It’s quite likely that that code tries to load itself somewhere, so you’re getting a recursion.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure none of your scripts inside ./R/ contains `load_all()`, as that would lead to `load_all()` recursively calling itself.

In my case, that's what led to exactly the behavior described above: I had a temporary script file with notes accidentally saved under ./R/ and `load_all()` was trying to load it. Moved it up to the main project directory and everything was fine.

Comment: This was a lifesaver!